# Change mapped drive path via command line/batch file

Tags: windows, batch-file, cmd

How do I change the path of a mapped drive via batch file?

I have written a batch file to delete files in various locations that are older than 2 weeks old.

```
net use Y: \\servername1\c$

cd /d Y:\Reports
SET _CmdResult=NONE
FOR /F "tokens=*" %%a IN ('forfiles -p "Y:\Reports" -s -m *.* -d -14 -c "cmd /c del @file" 2^>^&1 ^| FINDSTR ERROR') DO SET _CmdResult=%%a
IF "%_CmdResult%" == "ERROR: No files found with the specified search criteria." ( 
    SET errorlevel=0 
) ELSE ( 
    SET errorlevel=1
)
IF "%_CmdResult%" == "NONE" SET errorlevel=0

net use Y: /delete /y

timeout 10

net use Y: \\servername2\c$

cd /d Y:\Reports
SET _CmdResult=NONE
FOR /F "tokens=*" %%a IN ('forfiles -p "Y:\Reports" -s -m *.* -d -14 -c "cmd /c del @file" 2^>^&1 ^| FINDSTR ERROR') DO SET _CmdResult=%%a
IF "%_CmdResult%" == "ERROR: No files found with the specified search criteria." ( 
    SET errorlevel=0 
) ELSE ( 
    SET errorlevel=1
)
IF "%_CmdResult%" == "NONE" SET errorlevel=0

net use Y: /delete /y
```

The problem I have is that after the first instance of `net use Y: /delete /y` it closes the console down. Without the `/y` the console just waits for confirmation so never moves on.

I have tried removing the first instance of  `net use Y: /delete /y` from the script hoping the next command `net use Y: \\servername2\c$ /y` would just re-assign but it errors as already in use.

I know I could map various drives at the start of the script for the specific servers but if I want to use the script to delete files from a few servers that could get messy if a drive letter is already used at some point going forward, it also seems very inefficient (more so than my script probably already is)

I also could have multiple scripts for each server location but again think it would be neater handled in 1 script.

So is there a method of changing the path of a mapped drive?

Comment: What's the additional `/y` for in `net use Y: /delete /y`? Why are you using `Net Use` anyhow? Have you tried `PushD "\\networklocation"` then after having completed, use `PopD` to return the current directory back to where it was?

Comment: It suppresses a prompt that was asking if I wanted to disconnect the drive.

Comment: @Compo: [SS64](https://ss64.com/nt/net-use.html) lists that very command as `Disconnect from a share and close all resources (undocumented)`

Comment: Sorry @Stephan, but I have no intention of visiting any site for built-in command help, other than [Microsoft's own](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/previous-versions/windows/it-pro/windows-server-2012-r2-and-2012/gg651155(v%3Dws.11)) and you can clearly see that they use `/delete:{yes | no}`, _the same as they do with `/persistent`_, hence my question.

Comment: @Round: don't use `errorlevel` as a variable name. Windows uses an internal variable with that name and you might disable its proper function, which may lead to unexpected and hard to troubleshoot failures. That said, I can't reproduce your issue (WIN10) @Compo: my comment was just informational (indeed, I agree: stick to documented syntax unless you have a very good reason, not to).

Comment: You're only looking for a specific error from the forfiles recursive default glob with your date criteria. You're not looking for errors from the delete command, so I do not see any purpose in running forfiles as a for loop command. Here's a full, single line, untested, batch file example to try instead: `@(For %%G In ("\\servername1\c$\Reports","\\servername2\c$\Reports")Do @(PushD "%%G" 2>NUL&&((ForFiles /S /D -14 /C "Cmd /C Del /F/A @File"|FindStr /EL "criteria.">NUL||Echo No Report files to delete on %%G)&PopD)||Echo Unable to connect to %%G\Reports))>"output.log"`

Comment: Why do you need drive letters?  Just `net use \\host\share` and use the UNC to access files.

Comment: @jwdonahue. I tried the direct hostname but I was recieveing an error saying CMD does not support UNC paths as current directories

Comment: You don't need to make it the current directory.  Set a variable to the path and execute your commands against that path.

Answer (score 0):

This is what I have now. It appears to be working.
I will look into the single line solution too.

I couldn't leave as comment above as there was too much text...

```
pushd \\servername1\c$

cd /d Reports
SET _CmdResult=NONE
FOR /F "tokens=*" %%a IN ('forfiles -p "%cd%" -s -m *.* -d -14 -c "cmd /c del @file" 2^>^&1 ^| FINDSTR ERROR') DO SET _CmdResult=%%a
IF "%_CmdResult%" == "ERROR: No files found with the specified search criteria." ( 
    SET con1=0 
) ELSE ( 
    SET con1=1
)
IF "%_CmdResult%" == "NONE" SET con1=0

timeout 15

popd

timeout 15

pushd \\servername2\c$

cd /d Reports
SET _CmdResult=NONE
FOR /F "tokens=*" %%a IN ('forfiles -p "%cd%" -s -m *.* -d -14 -c "cmd /c del @file" 2^>^&1 ^| FINDSTR ERROR') DO SET _CmdResult=%%a
IF "%_CmdResult%" == "ERROR: No files found with the specified search criteria." ( 
    SET con1=0 
) ELSE ( 
    SET con1=1
)
IF "%_CmdResult%" == "NONE" SET con1=0

timeout 15

popd
```

Thanks for all suggestions and help above